# Product of two anodyne maps is anodyne

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Anodyne morphisms can be defined as the closure of horn inclusions $\Lambda^k_n\to \Delta^n$ along retracts, transfinite composition and pushouts. A nice result on these anodyne morphisms is that the pushout product map is again anodyne. That is, if $f:X\to Y$ and $i:A\to B$ are two monos, of which one of them is anodyne, then the map $$(A\times Y)\coprod_{X\times A}(B\times X)\to Y\times B$$ is anodyne.

From this lemma probably, it should be derivable from that the product of two anodyne maps is also anodyne. It suffices to show that for $f$ anodyne, the product $f\times id$ is anodyne, but I just fail to see this. Does someone have any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

edit: adding a diagram for the pushout product of $f$ with the identity. [image]

Which is the same as the following pushout product diagram

[image]

But this only says that the identity on $Y\times A$ is anodyne, which is not really a suprise. Probably I do really have some blind spot, or my category theory has gone too rusty.

Comment: All the ingredients required are literally in the first paragraph of your post. Draw the commutative diagram defining the pushout–product. The map you are interested in appears in the diagram!

Comment: Yes, that is what I expected, but unfortunately I haven't seen it appear so far. It must be some blind spot.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I had a thinko. The proof is quite involved. One way (in principle) is to show that the class of anodyne extensions that are preserved by $X \times  (-)$ is closed under pushout and transfinite composition and contains the horn inclusions. Another is to first prove that anodyne extensions are precisely the monomorphisms that are weak homotopy equivalences and then show that the weak homotopy equivalences are closed under binary products.